# SharePoint error "file or folder contains properties that will be lost at the new destination"

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, metadata

The implication of discussion on this issue is that to preserve metadata on files and folders one must have same custom content type on both the source and destination libraries. I have done this and yet have the warning of losing the metadata, and if I go ahead and do the move in fact the properties do not show in the folder.

Other discussion seems to glom thru this and accept the loss of the custom metadata. I would much rather fix the issue and retain the metadata having invested quite a bit in making it happen in the first place... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It has been said that the worst form of lie is the truth misunderstood. The insidious nature of this is hereby illustrated...

In this case, the custom metadata was totally intact in the destination library! This can be seen simply by looking at the properties of the item. The apparent lie in this case is that the default view displayed columns was different in the two libraries. Modifying the view to show the custom columns was all that was needed.... sigh!

This phenomenon does beg the question of why put up the warning message that the file or folder contains properties that will be lost... probably a column not present in the content type that was added to the first library... I think.